# Capturar error en imagen con Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Saludos tengo un inconveniente al momento de capturar un error en una imagen con Angular, ya que necesito mostrar una imagen cuando la que se trae da error, pero no logro poder capturar cuando una imagen da error

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y terminará cerrada, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

En la imagen hay una etiqueta Error que puedes manejar para estos casos, el código es similar a esto.

```
<!-- Asignas directamente el source en caso de error-->
<img src="assets/imagen1.jpg" alt="Foto" onError="this.src='assets/no disponible.jpg';">
```

Y el otro caso es mandarlo actualizar en tu component, por si quieres manejar algo dinámico.

```
<!-- HTML-->
<img [src]="assets/imagen1.jpg" (error)="imagenError($event)">

<!-- Componente-->

public imagenError(event: any) {
    let ruta = 'assets/no disponible.jpg';
    event.target.src = ruta;
}
```